# Creating a singleton object without an interface via Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, guice

I just heard from my Senior that I can not instantiate the concrete class as Singleton without using an interface in dependency injection even though I added the @Singleton annotation on that concrete class and it seamlessly work in the system. But doing that way, multiple instances of class is created instead, he mentioned.

I am working with Play Scala framework with Guice DI by the way.

I tried googling to verify if true but I can't find answer.

Can someone give me a concrete explanation? In java I can create a Singleton class without interface.

Comment: I don't know about scala too much, but you can definitely bind an instance class as a singleton like: bind(MyImpl.class).in(Singleton.class) in java. Since java and scala work quite well together (and I assume guice is the scala adoption of the java framework) it seems unlikely that that wouldn't be possible? You can write a really quick test for that yourself though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of keeping a record, I will post my answer.

I tried to extend the experiment of @AlexanderArendar:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton

/**
  * Created by Alex on 7/27/2016.
  */
@Singleton
class JustASingleton {
  def giveMeFive = "5"
}
```

First Controller

```
class MainController @Inject()(
                                environment:play.api.Environment,
                                documentService:DocumentService,
                                userService:UserService,
                                singletonInstance:JustASingleton
                              )(implicit ec:ExecutionContext)extends Controller {


  def testSingletonInjection() = Action(Ok("controller id " + System.identityHashCode(this).toString + " and Injected Bean id " + System.identityHashCode(singletonInstance).toString))
  ...
```

Second Controller

```
class SecondController @Inject()(
                                    environment:play.api.Environment,
                                    documentService:DocumentService,
                                    userService:UserService,
                                    singletonInstance:JustASingleton
                                  )(implicit ec:ExecutionContext)extends Controller {
    
    
      def testSingletonInjection() = Action(Ok("controller id " + System.identityHashCode(this).toString + " and Injected Bean id " + System.identityHashCode(singletonInstance).toString))
      ...
```

Then in routes

```
GET     /singletonX                  controllers.MainController.testSingletonInjection

GET     /singletonY                  controllers.SecondController.testSingletonInjection
```

And calling these 2 endpoints gave me the following results:

> controller id 1944357758 and Injected Bean id 853668078
>
> controller id 943948501 and Injected Bean id 853668078

As I can conclude based on the test, that the concrete class can be created as Singleton without having to provide an Interface

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is whether it is possible to inject a class right away without a "companion" train and binding trait to implementation in Module then it is possible.
I have just experimented. Here goes my simple class:
package services

```
import javax.inject.Singleton

/**
  * Created by Alex on 7/27/2016.
  */
@Singleton
class JustASingleton {
  def giveMeFive = "5"
}
```

Then in my controller I am injecting it without any trait (interface as you called it):

```
class MainController @Inject()(
                                environment:play.api.Environment,
                                documentService:DocumentService,
                                userService:UserService,
                                singletonInstance:JustASingleton
                              )(implicit ec:ExecutionContext)extends Controller {


  def testSingletonInjection() = Action(Ok(singletonInstance.giveMeFive))
  ...
```

Then in routes I have the line:

```
GET     /singleton                  controllers.MainController.testSingletonInjection
```

It compiles ok and when I go to localhost:9000/singleton then i get a proper html response. So injection without a trait and binding an implementation to a trait does work.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Yeah, your sample does work. What I would like to know if JustASingleton class really creates only one instance object.

Comment: Well, javadoc of this annotation says `Identifies a type that the injector only instantiates once.`. I can't say for 100% sure that I can guarantee that, neither can reliably test this, but usually I tend to believe what documentation says :)

Comment: I put a test with slight change from your sample comment, and I can conclude that instance is indeed singleton.